# Delegate equality after casting

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am trying to cast a `WaitCallBack` into an `Action<object>`

I am doing this by:

```
WaitCallBack w1 = Foo;

Action<object> a1 = new Action<object>(w1);
Action<object> a2 = Foo;
```

However, when i try to compare the `a1` with `a2`, it will return `false`.

Is there away to cast the delegates, so that the equality will be true?

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't *casting* the delegate; you are *wrapping* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates compare by method+target; the problem is that you are comparing different things!

Perhaps it becomes clearer if we expand this line to what the compiler sees:

```
Action<object> a1 = new Action<object>(w1);
```

is actually:

```
Action<object> a1 = new Action<object>(w1.Invoke);
```

(using the implicit `Invoke` operation on a delegate)

You you can see that the target is `w1`, and the method is `Invoke`. We can confirm this:

```
Console.WriteLine(a1.Method.Name); // Invoke
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a1.Target, w1)); // true
```

Compare to the other:

```
Action<object> a2 = Foo;
```

Here, the target is either `null` (if static) or `this` (if non-static), and the method is `Foo`. The delegates **are not the same**. It is correct that it reports `false`.

You can check this *chained* operation manually, but it is a bit tedious, especially if you need to consider every combination/depth; but a trivial example:

```
Delegate del = a1.Target as Delegate;
if(del != null)
{
    if(del.Method == a2.Method && del.Target == a2.Target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pass");
    }
}
```